# Populating a table on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

The following code works but I'm trying to work out what one particular line does. The line in question is:

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('{}',"+"{},"*14+"{})"
```

It belongs to the following block of code:

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO state_percentages VALUES ('{}',"+"{},"*14+"{})"
with open('C:\\Users\conno\\OneDrive\\weather.csv', 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     next(reader) # skip the header
     for row in reader:
         dbCursor.execute(insertString.format(*row))
 dbCursor.close()
```

Thanks
Pat

Answer (score 1):

It creates a line that will be filled by `.format(*row)` later on:

```
template = "INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('{}',{},{})"
formatted = template.format('foo', 123, -1)
print(formatted) # INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('foo',123,-1)
```

- The `"{}, " * 14` just repeats the template placeholder 14 times.
- The `*row` just fills in list values as if you manually listed them all: `.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], ...)`
- The quotes around template placeholder `'{}'` are there only because strings have to be surrounded by `'` in PostgreSQL. (See the `'foo'` in example above).

**Important note**: Filling in **un**sanitized values like this is unsecure. For secure implementation, do what @adrian-klaver suggested in comments.